# Using Phonegap to create Android apps connect via bluetooth

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an Android app using Phonegap and I need it to communicate to a Portable Receipt Printer in order to print out delivery dates and items. Is it possible with Phonegap? If so any tips on how do I go along with it? Thanks

Comment: How is the portable receipt printer connected to the android device?

Comment: According to the hardware dealer, they have their SDK for the printer. Hence for my apps, I need to combine together with their SDK. The printer is something like this http://www.posguys.com/mobile-printers_55/Epson-Epson-Mobilink-TM-P60II_2338/

Comment: It looks like that printer uses bluetooth - you need to look if you can do that in phonegap (maybe something like https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/23 )

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot Lachlan. May have to trial and error on it.